# Memory consumption of java Collection.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, memory, collections, heap-memory

I have an ArrayList filled with 1.5 million objects of some class. When I sort this list by usage of the Collection.sort method the allocated memory of the JVM increases dramatically.

So my questions are:

Is that normal? What could be reasons for that? Is this a matter of the garbage collector working too slowly or not being started often enough? Do the objects in the list have to fulfill certain specifications to consume less memory during sort (besides not containing that much data)?

Thx!

Comment: You might want to consider quicksort or heapsort or another memory efficient sort over TIMSort which is usually faster.

Comment: Java 8 or an older Java version?

Comment: Does your class implement `Comparable` or are you using a custom `Comparator`? What does the `compareTo` implementation look like?

Comment: I'm using Java 8. Thx for the thought about a different sorting algorithm, will look into it. I use a custom Comparator.

Comment: I would also like to point out that storing that many objects in a list might lead to the conclusion that the design can be improved. Try to calculate the size of you object in bytes and then multiply it with 1.5 million, just to get some idea of how much memory it takes up.
I would avoid storing that many object in a list, but if it cannot be avoided, try with some more efficient algorithm as others suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to sort a `List`, the [default sorting implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%29) first creates an array-copy of all elements that are to be sorted. This causes the additional heap consumption that you observe while sorting. This copying is necessary since a generic sorting algorithm has no knowledge of the list's structure, for example if it is random-access or not.

For Java 8, the [sorting implementation was however changed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%29) to be delegated to each implementation of a `List`. This became possible with using default methods. For an `ArrayList`, this additional overhead [could be removed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.sort%28java.util.Comparator%29) by implementing a more efficient sorting algorithm. An upgrade to Java 8 would therefore most likely resolve your problem.

There is nothing wrong with garbage collection for your problem. Large arrays are unfortunately heavy to handle because they probably do not fit into the young generation and can eventually trigger a full collection.

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments, the actual sorting is [performed via *Tim Sort* since Java 7](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) by the `Arrays::sort` implementation. *Tim sort* requires additional heap space. From the javadoc:

> Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted
>   input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

<del>If this is not applicable for your use case, you can switch back to the previous merge-sort implementation by setting the system property `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` to `true`.</del>

After all, *Tim sort* is however still more efficient than merge sort as merge sort requires another full array copy.

Comment: This. This plus _"Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays."_ which is an implementation note of Timsort for all current `sort()` methods working on non-primitive data.